# Spring Kafka listener using DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer and manual ack mode

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

I'm having a hard time to understand how this could be solved so I'm asking it here in the hope someone else already faced the same problems.
We are running our @KafkaListener with manual ack mode and a dead letter recoverer with a retry limit of 3. 
Manual ack mode is needed due to the business logic that we dont ack a message and pause consuming for 5 minutes when certain circumstances are given (external dependencies).

Also we do need the dead letter queue for messages we cannot process for some reason.

Now the problem in manual ack mode is that our listener/consumer does not acknowledge the message when he hits the retry limit and moves it to the dl queue.

If the consumer service will be restarted he tries to consume the messages again and again will move them to the dl queue.

Any ideas how we could solve this issue?

Thanks and greetings from Hamburg!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to avoid using manual acks if possible; perhaps by increasing `max.poll.interval.ms` instead.

If you use `AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE`, it will be safe to perform the commit directly on the `Consumer` in the error handler.

Subclass the `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` and override `handle()`, If `super.handle()` doesn't throw an exception, it means the retries are exceeded and you can commit the offset on the `Consumer`.

Comment: We are using AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE already. Thanks for the fast answer and the easy solution Gary!
Respect and big thanks you for helping the community here on stackoverflow that much on all the kafka topics!

Comment: Hi I am having the same issue. Can you please share some sample code to indicate how you solved the issue as I have not really understood the solution mentioned here. I am using DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer along with SeekToCurrentErrorHandler and ackOnError(true). This seems to not ack the message on original topic as you mentioned above.

Comment: Please let me know if the suggestion is something like this   @Override
    public void handle(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {
        super.handle(thrownException, records, consumer, container);
        consumer.commitAsync();
    }

Comment: Yes, except `super.handle(...);` should be in a try/catch which re-throws the exception (if thrown) and commits the offset via the `Consumer` when there is no exception (because that means the record was sent to the DLT). The ack mode MUST BE MANUAL_IMMEDIATE for this to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary. Much appreciate your help here. Just one more question. Why use try/catch around super.handle(...) when we have to only call consumer.commitAsync() ONLY in case of no exception from super.handle(...) i.e. when item has been successfully moved to DLT? My requirement is to commit in the source topic only on successfully processing or successfully publishing to DLT. So wouldnt my code snippet without try/catch do the same as with try/catch (rethrow) and then commit only when no exception? May be I am missing something?

Comment: Sorry - it's hard to read code in comments (better to edit the answer next time :) ). I didn't notice the commit. You shouldn't use that method, though; you should only commit the offset for the failed record (first in the list). Using that version, offsets for the unprocessed records will also be committed (which we only just performed the seeks for so they will get redelivered).

Comment: Thanks again Gary. Can you please share some code may be answer as you said as it seems its bit involved to commit specific offset using consumer object. Also what is your thought on handling this in Spring-Kafka for e.g. a new subclass of SeekToCurrentErrorHandler with DLT recoverer and also being able to commit the offset of failing message once it has been successfully moved to DLT. Basically a new class that does what you are suggesting to do in my application.

Comment: Yes; I was thinking the same thing; I issued a [pull request here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/pull/961). The code is a bit more involved than you might need because we have to honor the `syncCommits` property, but hopefully you can see what's needed for a local solution.

Answer (score 1):

commitRecovered can be set to true on SeekToCurrentErrorHandler instance being provided to the ContainerListenerFactory.

Refer documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.html#setCommitRecovered-boolean-)

> public void setCommitRecovered(boolean commitRecovered)
>
> Set to true to commit the offset for a recovered record. The container must be >configured with ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE. Whether or not the >commit is sync or async depends on the container's syncCommits property.

Comment: In my opinion this should be the approved answer since creating a subclass (like the approved answer suggests) seems unnecessary if there is an actual configuration for that.